# How to detect if a function has a return statement

Tags: javascript

I am writing an assertion library for javascript. I want the assertions to be chainable, so each assertion needs to call

`return this;`

so that more assertions can be run on it.

What I want to do is write a test that will check if each assertion has the return statement. I can think of two solutions for this, and I'm not sure I like either of them.

1. Problematic solution - in my test I can call each assertion and see if it returns a value. This is problematic because I can't know if the assertion is going to return successfully or throw an assertion error. Ideally I'd call all of the assertions in a loop so I can call them the same way.
2. Hacky solution - I can call `.toString()` on each assertion and use regex to look for the string `return this` in the body of the function. I suppose this would work pretty well because I could account for any amount of whitespace in the regex, but that wouldn't stop trying to work around the solution by putting the string in an unreachable branch of code such as `if(!true) return this`.

I think #2 is probably simpler, but I don't love it. Does anyone have any other solutions?

Edit: Sample code for how I would like to write these tests:

```
var assertionFns = getAssertionFns(); // actual generation process not relevant

assertionFns.forEach(function(fn){
    test(fnReturnsAValue(fn));
});

function fnReturnsAValue(fn){
    // What goes here?
}

function test(value){
    if(!value){
        // fail the test
    }
}
```

Just to reiterate why #1 is problematic, `fn` will throw an `AssertionError` if the assertion is failed, assuming I actually execute the function.

I hope this clarifies, please let me know if it does not.

Comment: Solution 3: Convert the assertion function to a string, use a parser to generate an AST and traverse it looking for `return this;`. However, I don't see a problem with #1. I guess you would write other tests to ensure that each assertion works correctly. Testing the return value would just be one additional test (for each assertion) and you'd provide an empty to fulfills the assertion.

Comment: You mention chaining, but you also mention calling them in a loop. How are you planning on running through your list of assertions? Some sample code there would help, I think.

Comment: I agree, solution 1 seems like it should do, if `this` is expected to be an instance of `Assertion` then you could check like `assertFn() instanceof Assertion` right?

Comment: Apologies for the lack of sample code. I could write a test for each assertion (not convinced that I won't be doing that). What I was hoping for was something that I could use for *all* assertions now and future. I'll add some sample code now.

Comment: Don't you just need to check that calling the function doesn't return *undefined*? Or that it returns an object (say either the object expected or an error object)?

Comment: @RobG the problem with that approach is that there is not  a way to guarantee that the assertion will pass. In general terms, if the assertion does not pass, the function will throw an AssertionError.

Comment: Ok, so can you call the function and set its *this* to a known suitable object, then check that is the object that's returned? Of course calling the function might have undesirable consequences… :-/

Comment: The second part of your statement is the tricky part. Even if I mock in the object that the assertion is running against, I am still calling the function which I won't be changing.

Comment: To anyone viewing this looking for answers, I decided that this isn't something I want to implement, so I won't be pursuing the answer any longer.

Comment: You could just append `return this` to the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

How about just checking if it doesn't return undefined?  If the function just says

```
return;
```

in it, then yes, it will still return undefined.  However if the function has

```
return false;
```

in it (or any other value - including objects, numbers, etc), then the following test will determine if a function has a return

```
function fnReturnsAValue(fn){
    if (typeof(fn)=="function" && typeof(fn())!="undefined") { return true; }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: See the OP's comment on the question: "the problem with that approach is that there is not a way to guarantee that the assertion will pass. In general terms, if the assertion does not pass, the function will throw an AssertionError."